# Pushing selected Git branches/tags to new remote

Tags: git

I have a Git repository **A** with 25 branches and 14 tags. The full size of **A** is 2.5 GB.

I only use 3-4 of these branches tags and would really like to reduce the size of **A** (I don't care about the history from the other branches). I have therefore created a new remote **B** and will push those selected branches/tags to that new remote **B**.

But since all commits reachable from those selected branches/tags will be available in the new remote **B** I guess I could potentially end up having the same size in the new repository **B** again?

And further could I create a "corrupt" remote **B** if I only push selected branches/tags and not all of them? E.g. assume that I push a tag **t0** but I have not pushed the branch that it was created from.

Answer (score 0):

> But since all commits reachable from those selected branches/tags will be available in the new remote B I guess I could potentially end up having the same size in the new repository B again?

Yes, Git will include in your new repository however many blobs it needs to represent all the branches you push there.

> And further could I create a "corrupt" remote B if I only push selected branches/tags and not all of them? E.g. assume that I push a tag t0 but I have not pushed the branch that it was created from.

This is not likely unless you do some serious messing with Git under the hood.  When you push each branch from repo A to repo B, Git will handle its objects (trees and blobs) automatically.  So it will "bring in" whatever it needs to complete the operation.